# python 2.7 permutation of string starting from index

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, indexing, permutation

I want to have the permutation of string in python:

```
 string= asis:abc
    permutations = ["".join(x) for x in permutations(string,len(string))] 
        print permutations
```

But I need to start in this example after the : i.e I want to obtain something like this:

```
asis:abc, asis:acb, asis:bca, asis:bac, ...
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: `permutations = ...permutations(...)` This is a bad idea. You're blowing away the function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from itertools import permutations

s = 'asis:abc'
delimiter = ':'
pre, post = s.split(delimiter)
for p in permutations(post):
    print '{}{}{}'.format(pre, delimiter, ''.join(p))
```

Output:

```
asis:abc
asis:acb
asis:bac
asis:bca
asis:cab
asis:cba
```

Or you can store the values in a list by replacing the for loop with a list comprehension:

```
perms = ['{}{}{}'.format(pre, delimiter, ''.join(p)) for p in permutations(post)]
```